# Android Google login not working inside WebView

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, android-webview, google-oauth

I am new to android development. Trying to integrate FB and Google+ login in Android web view. FB login is working fine. But Google login is not allowing to login. I referred a few links but unable to succeed.

Problem is after providing user name and password in Gmail my web site is not sign in

[A webview overlay over another webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839965/a-webview-overlay-over-another-webview)

[Google sign in not working android webview app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125741/google-sign-in-not-working-android-webview-app)

[Google sign in not working android webview app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125741/google-sign-in-not-working-android-webview-app)

```
private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
        Log.d("Loading URL", url);
        if (host.equals(target_url_prefix)) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load
            // the page
            if (mWebviewPop != null) {
                mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
                mWebviewPop = null;
            }
            return false;
        }

        if (host.contains("m.facebook.com") || host.contains("facebook.co")
                || host.contains("google.co")
                || host.contains("www.facebook.com")
                || host.contains(".google.com")
                || host.contains(".google")
                || host.contains("accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/consent")
                || host.contains("accounts.youtube.com")
                || host.contains("accounts.google.com")
                || host.contains("accounts.google.co.in")
                || host.contains("www.accounts.google.com")
                || host.contains("oauth.googleusercontent.com")
                || host.contains("content.googleapis.com")
                || host.contains("ssl.gstatic.com")
            //     || host.contains("https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/consent")

        ) {
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch
        // another Activity that handles URLs

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "onReceivedSslError");
        super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("https://m.facebook.com/v2.7/dialog/oauth")


        ) {
            if (mWebviewPop != null) {
                mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
                mWebviewPop = null;
            }
            view.loadUrl("https://www.cbazaar.com");
            return;
        }

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}

private class UriWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        mWebviewPop = new WebView(mContext);
        mWebviewPop.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mWebviewPop.setWebChromeClient(new UriWebChromeClient());
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.clearHistory();
        mWebviewPop.clearFormData();
        mWebviewPop.clearCache(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setUserAgentString(USER_AGENT_FAKE);

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT).create();

        builder.setTitle("");
        builder.setView(mWebviewPop);

        builder.setButton("close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                mWebviewPop.destroy();
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        builder.show();
        builder.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);

             /*   CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebviewPop,true);
                }
    */

        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {

        try {
            mWebviewPop.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            builder.dismiss();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: No. Please paste some code when you implemented google sign here.

Comment: Refer this link [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview)

Comment: TruongHieu , please find the code above

Answer (score 19):

You have to create a custom webchromeclient and handle the popup from webview. Whenever there will requirement of popup from website, you have to load it in alert dialog.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webViewPopUp;
private AlertDialog builder;
private Context globalContext;

private String url = "https://www.bellyfulstore.com/";

private WebView webView;
private String userAgent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(url);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Set User Agent
    userAgent = System.getProperty("http.agent");
    webSettings.setUserAgentString(userAgent + "yourAppName");

    // Enable Cookies
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);

    // Handle Popups
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new CustomChromeClient());
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    globalContext = this.getApplicationContext();

    // WebView Tweaks
    webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);



    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // do your stuff here
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}




class CustomChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                  boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        webViewPopUp = new WebView(globalContext);
        webViewPopUp.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webViewPopUp.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webViewPopUp.setWebChromeClient(new CustomChromeClient());
        webViewPopUp.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webViewPopUp.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webViewPopUp.getSettings().setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
        webViewPopUp.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent + "yourAppName");

        // pop the  webview with alert dialog
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WebViewActivity.this).create();
        builder.setTitle("");
        builder.setView(webViewPopUp);

        builder.setButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                webViewPopUp.destroy();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
        builder.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webViewPopUp, true);
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
        }

        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(webViewPopUp);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
        //Toast.makeText(contextPop,"onCloseWindow called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            webViewPopUp.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Destroyed with Error ", e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }

        try {
            builder.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Dismissed with Error: ", e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView!=null){
        if (webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
            return;
        }
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

Comment: swift version available ?

Comment: thanks for share this working things....
But when i add this code my apps takes almost 2 to min time to load going my web page.....can you tell me how can i fix this issue ?

Comment: Your answer still work like a charm! Thanks! But.. how can i specify to open it only for login button? For now any link on my website in webview is opened in popup.. Thanks for any feedback !

Comment: I wantn't recommend to use an application context for this, but in general it's the great solution, thanks

Answer (score 16):

Google does not allow default implementations of WebView to be used. Therefore you need to set a custom User-Agent to your WebView:

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("YourAppName");
```

You can use any string instead of `YourAppName`.

Comment: @GirishM where do you create/findById() WebView first?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Its not working, is there any way to catch the error?

Comment: @HarpreetSingh And how does that make it "not work"?

Comment: didn't say "not work", but it raises alarm to user, just my thought@VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: after adding the line...it redirect to desktop view of website instead of mobile view

Comment: works in Fully Kiosk Browser in Settings/Advanced web settings / Custom user agent string...

Answer (score 10):

Late answer but may help somebody in future.

Actually Google Blocks OAuth Requests Made Via Embedded Browsers. so you can write something like in your code:

```
 public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Galaxy Nexus Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19";
 mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(USER_AGENT);
```

or you can do like this:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("yourAppName");
```

and you should be able to use sign in with google.

Answer (score -1):

```
webSettings.setUserAgentString(webSettings.getUserAgentString().replace("; wv",""));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -8):

If you use firebase for your application. I think you can find a workaround here: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Good luck!